# Click eventListener happening on load instead of on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the backgroundColor of the `drumkey` class when clicking on a `p` element. However, it is instantly applying when loading the page instead of `onClick`.

```
var keyEl = document.getElementsByClassName("drumKey");
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", colorChange(i));
}

function colorChange(i) {
    keyEl[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because [`addEventListener` requires a `function` as a second parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) and you are calling to execute a function instead of returning a function.

Remember that [functions are objects in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp). You can just return a function like this:

```js
var keyEl = document.getElementsByClassName("drumKey");
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", colorChange(i));
}

function colorChange(i) {
  return function(){
    keyEl[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }    
}
```

```html
<div class="drumKey">This is div 1</div>
<div class="drumKey">This is div 2</div>
<div class="drumKey">This is div 3</div>
<div class="drumKey">This is div 4</div>


<p>Click here to change the background color to red of Div 1</p>
<p>Click here to change the background color to red of Div 2</p>
<p>Click here to change the background color to red of Div 3</p>
<p>Click here to change the background color to red of Div 4</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

so, your mistake that you call function when assign an event, but you need return it, like below

```
x[i].addEventListener("click", (i) => colorChange(i));
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers, working or not.